# Not able to import Sring Boot Project using Spring Intialization, gradle uild error regarding property 'snippetsDir'

Tags: eclipse

I am trying to add a Spring Boot Project into my Oxygen Eclipse IDE by selecting the below SpringBoot versions and Dependencies

```
Spring Boot Version: 1.5.19
Dependencies: Web, Rest Docs
Gradle Version: Gradle 5.2.1
```

Getting the below error regarding the gradle build issue

> Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Could not get unknown
>   property 'snippetsDir' for task ':test' of type
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.

Can any one pls let me know how to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

yoou need set the output.dir, just like this in build.gradle

```
ext {
  snippetsDir =  file('build/generated-snippets')
}
```

at root level